# Using form_for for one-to-one relation model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-for, belongs-to, has-one

I have a one-to-one models for user and profile.

The following is the code for the `User` model created by device.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :profile , dependent: :destroy
end
```

Code for `Profile` model.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

Now I have basic `Profile` for a `User` which was created at sign up. Now how do I go about editing user profile using the helper device provides `current_user` with `form_for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :build_profile
end
```

This populates the profile record in the database, allowing you to update it later on

Once you've saved the user, you will be best using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to populate & save `profile` options through a form for the user, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :profiles 
end

#app/views/profiles/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
     <%= f.text_field :your_profile_options %>
<% end %>
```

This is a very basic way to do it, but hopefully will give you more ideas. If you want to see this in the wild, check out http://video-conference-demo.herokuapp.com (it uses Devise to handle users & has extra "profile" model too)